# Calculate the co occurrence in file text

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have one list, one file text and one string

```
list1 = ['man', 'girl', 'woman']
str = "work"
text_file
```

What needed is to calculate the co occurrence of the string "work" with every item in the list1, when both of them occur in the same line in the text_file.

I tried this

```
n_occurrence = 0
for line in text_file:
    for item in list1:
        if item in line and str in line:
            n_occurrence +=1
```

This code calculates the co occurrence of str with all the elements of the list, but I want the co occurrence of str separately with each item in the list.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
from collections import defaultdict
n_occurence = defaultdict(lambda:0)
for line in text_file:
    for item in list1:
        if item in line and str in line:
            n_occurence[item] +=1
```

Comment: In this case, when I want to select the items above one certain threshold, and I make : if n_occurence.values()> 5, I get the error: TypeError: unorderable types: dict_values() > int()

Comment: `n_occurence` is a dict here. And python itself doesn't support array comparison. You need to run `print [(k,v) for k,v in n_occurence.items() if v>5]` or simpler `[x for x in n_occurence.values() if x>5]`